# Await for event from child component Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child and a parent component.
The flow is: In parent I have "Save changes"-> I have one method that update it -> also in child I have an method to update a part of the component , but if I have duplicate value first emits the Update from parent and after that I got error from Child, and I want to await for a answer from child until I update parent component.

**Parent:**

```
<b-btn @click="updateCustomer">Save Changes</b-btn>
<display-pr @duplicateValue="valueDuplicate"></display-pr>

    updateCustomer() {
        if(this.duplicateValue){
           //error message
        }else{
            //do something
        }
    }
    valueDuplicate(duplicateValue) {
        this.duplicateValue = duplicateValue;
    },
```

**Child**

```
updateCustomerName(){
   //find if I have duplicate and if I have let duplicate=  true;
   if(duplicate){
        this.$emit('duplicateValue',duplicateValue);
   }
   else {
        //post
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable "Save Changes" button for click event at parent component until finishing up checking duplication at child component. if you check duplication from network call, you should use asynchronous javascript paradigm.

**parent**

```js
<template>
   <b-btn @click="updateCustomer">Save Changes :disabled="isSaveBtnDisabled"</b-btn>
   <display-pr @duplicateValue="valueDuplicate"></display-pr>
   <child-component @checkDuplicates="changeSaveBtnStatus"></child-component>
</template>

<script>
    data: () => {
        isSaveBtnDisabled: false
    },
    methods: {
        changeSaveBtnStatus: (event) => {
            this.isSaveBtnDisabled = event;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Child**

```js
updateCustomerName: () => {
        this.$emit('checkDuplicates', true);
        /*
         * Here is code statements the checking duplicates and enable save button by calling
         * this.$emit('checkDuplicates', false);
         *
         */
        this.$emit('checkDuplicates', false);
       if(duplicate){
            this.$emit('duplicateValue',duplicateValue);
       }
       else {/***post ***/}
    }
```